# MS Visual Studio: Display schema names in Server Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, database-schema

Good day, colleagues!

In our database all the stored procedures are binded to shemas, i.e.

```
Schema1.p_Procdeure1
Schema1.p_Procdeure2
Schema2.p_Procdeure1
```

But when I browse stored procs in Server Explorer in Visual Studio - it doesnt display shema names, i.e.

```
p_Procdeure1
p_Procdeure2
p_Procdeure1
```

It keeps sorting by schema names at first, but doesn`t display schema names! So, when you need to find exact procedure by name - you begin to suffer... Especially when there are tons of procedures...

Maybe anyone knows how to force displaying schema names in Server Explorer of MSVS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It`s sad, but only now I noticed that schema name is displaying! But it is shown in the end of procedure name in brackets! (Unfortunately I cannot upload images)

So, the problem was in my wondrous inattention! I was looking for schema names for several hours and even started this topic!

But anyway, it will be much more comfortable and habitual if schema names will display in the begining of a string like in Enterprise Manager!